# Apache Ignite: setNodeFilter for Ignite DataGrid not working

Tags: ignite

I have set my servers and client peerClassLoadingEnabled flag to true. 
I was able to see that peerClassLoadingEnabled is working fine for compute tasks.

However, while creating cache on a specific set of nodes using 
CacheConfiguration.setNodeFilter(...), I see the below error on server side.

```
2018-01-26 07:52:28,563][INFO ][exchange-worker-#42][time] Started exchange init [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=29, minorTopVer=0], crd=true, evt=NODE_JOINED, evtNode=649c5360-7060-40cf-9454-ad6d08be2a7c, customEvt=null, allowMerge=true]
[2018-01-26 07:52:28,563][INFO ][exchange-worker-#42][GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture] Finish exchange future [startVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=29, minorTopVer=0], resVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=29, minorTopVer=0], err=null]
[2018-01-26 07:52:28,564][INFO ][exchange-worker-#42][time] Finished exchange init [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=29, minorTopVer=0], crd=true]
[2018-01-26 07:52:28,564][INFO ][exchange-worker-#42][GridCachePartitionExchangeManager] Skipping rebalancing (nothing scheduled) [top=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=29, minorTopVer=0], evt=NODE_JOINED, node=649c5360-7060-40cf-9454-ad6d08be2a7c]
[2018-01-26 07:52:29,963][INFO ][grid-nio-worker-tcp-comm-0-#25][TcpCommunicationSpi] Accepted incoming communication connection [locAddr=/10.0.0.3:47100, rmtAddr=/183.82.140.186:31996]
**[2018-01-26 07:52:41,461][ERROR][tcp-disco-msg-worker-#3][TcpDiscoverySpi] Failed to unmarshal discovery custom message.
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to find class with given class loader for unmarshalling (make sure same versions of all classes are available on all nodes or enable peer-class-loading) [clsLdr=sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@764c12b6,**
```

based on the logs, it looks DataNodeFilter class was supposed to migrate from client to server and the class is not found. 
cacheCfg.setNodeFilter(new DataNodeFilter());

I have enabled PeerClassLoading flag as mentioned above

Any idea on why this could be happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately peer class loading doesn't work for anything related to
*CacheConfiguration*. Cache configurations are distributed over discovery messages, and peer class loading is not applied to them.

The workaround here is to use a configurable node filter, that will be deployed on all nodes. For example, *AttributeNodeFilter* is available in Ignite. It can filter out nodes, based on configured node attributes.

Comment: well, the CacheConfiguration api is poorly documented. But the workaround you suggested works for me

Comment: While creating table via SQL, I had to set cache template with the create   template as well. In the cache template, used setNodeFilter with AttributeNodeFilter. With this, I was able to create the table via SQL on specific nodes